# What does $ENV mean in CMake

Tags: c++, linux, cmake

What does `$ENV` mean in CMake? For example:

```
set(BOOST_ROOT $ENV{HOME}/dev/cpp/thirdparty/boost)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$ENV` is used to get the value of an environment variable <sup>[1]</sup>.

In your example, `$ENV{HOME}` would get the value of the environment variable `$HOME`. Let's say `$HOME` has a value of `/home/wls`. Running the snippet you showed would set the CMake variable `BOOST_ROOT` to `/home/wls/dev/cpp/thirdparty/boost`.

`$ENV` is not limited to being used with `$HOME`. You can use it for any environment variable that is available.

Note that there is `ENV` that is used with `set()` as well. Note that this `ENV` is not the same as `$ENV`. `ENV` is typically used this way in `set()`:

```
set(ENV{<variable>} [<value>])
```

`ENV` in the aforementioned context is used to denote that the variable you are setting the value of is an environment variable. As said in the documentation for `set()` <sup>[2]</sup>, changing an environment variable this way will affect the resulting value of later reads of that variable using `$ENV`.

References:

- [1] https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/ENV.html
- [2] https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html#set-environment-variable